# Check whether subgroup is normal in $ S_4$

Tags: group-theory, symmetric-groups, normal-subgroups

Let H={e,(12)(34)} and K ={e, (12)(34), (13)(24), (14)(23)} be subgroups of $ S_4$ where e is identity element. Then which of following is true

1. H and K are normal subgroups of $S_4$
2. H is normal in K and K is normal in$ A_4$
3. H is normal in $A_4$, but not normal in $ S_4$
4. K is normal in $S_4$ but H is not

How should this question be approached, checking left and right cosets of these subgroup is very time consuming. Checking gh$ g^{-1}$ $\in $ H for every g in $ S_4$ is also time consuming.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two elements in $S_n$ are conjugated if and only if they have the same factoriziation to disjoint cycels.

Hence $K$ is normal in $S_4$ and therefore in $A_4$.

From the same reason
$H$ is not normal in $S_4$.

$H$ is normal in $K$ since it is a subgroup of index $2$.

I left for you to cheack if $H$ is normal in $A_4$.

Comment: If elements are conjugated, why would k be normal?

Comment: @Foggy , let $k=(ab)(cd)$ where $\{a,b,c,d\}=\{1,2,3,4\}$ be an element in $S_4$ and let $g$ be another element. Then $g^{-1}kg=(xy)(zw)$ where $\{x,y,z,w\}=\{1,2,3,4\}$. Since all the elements of the form $(xy)(zw)$ are in $K$ it is stable under conjugation$=$ normal.

Comment: This rule holds for S_n, and A_n also?

Comment: Yes and no.. the difference is in $S_n$ any two elements are conjugated if and only if they have the same factorization to cycels. In $A_n$ you have just the "only if" part. That is, if two elements in $A_n$ are conjugated then they have that same factorization to cycels. The converse is not true.